# How can I convert a Pandas Series to a Numpy Array and maintain order?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `pandas` series that looks like:

```
cash          50121.599128
num_shares      436.000000
cost_basis      114.400002
open_price      113.650002
close_10        114.360001
close_9         115.769997
close_8         114.800003
close_7         114.040001
close_6         115.680000
close_5         115.930000
close_4         115.430000
close_3         113.339996
close_2         114.870003
close_1         114.050003
dtype: float64
```

I want to convert it to a `numpy` array, so I'm doing:

```
next_state_val = np.array([next_state.values])
```

However, there's no guarantee that my `series` will always have the same order. How can I maintain the same order across many series?

Comment: Can you provide an example where this doesn't happen as I've never seen where this happens, also you can just do `next_state_val = next_state.values`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the indices are always the same (but not necessarily occurring in the same order), you can use `.sort_index()` on the series. This will ensure the series is consistently ordered by its index each time.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the docs correctly, the `.values` method returns an array and preserves order.

Comment: I understand the question as saying that the series itself isn't always ordered the same way - could be happening if the data is read from an unordered source.

Comment: Ah, I see. In this case, I think that @ChristophBurschka 's answer will do the trick. You can also choose another index, not necessarily sorted, using the `.reindex` or the `.reindex_like` methods